# Subview cannot be found

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 4.2 and I having a problem with including sub-views.
I have a folder called 'header' in my views and header.php in that folder. Looks like this:

```
/app/views/header/header.php
```

I have already dump-autoloaded the project directory.
In my view (index.php), I have

```
@include('header.header')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the blade extension on your index.php file

```
index.blade.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.blade.php` extension to your view, in order using partial views..